# Query shows each row twice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

It shows each row twice... I wrote it to pick some rows from different tables, it shows what I want but it shows those rows twice, each. why ?

```
SELECT
   tbluser.fullname, tbluser.email, tblJobAdv.advtitle, tblPersonalInfo.country, 
   tblPersonalInfo.city, tblJobOffer.digitalsignature 
FROM
   tblUser 
LEFT JOIN
   tblPersonalInfo ON tblUser.userid = tblPersonalInfo.userid
LEFT JOIN
   tblApplication ON tblApplication.userid = tblUser.userid 
LEFT JOIN
   tblJobAdv ON tblJobAdv.advid = tblApplication.advid
LEFT JOIN
   tblJobOffer ON tblUser.userid = tblJobOffer.userid
WHERE
   tblJobAdv.userId IN (SELECT userid FROM tblUser WHERE email = 'h@y.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using 'group by' or 'distinct' makes your query slow and inefficient.
I think you would better finding duplicated rows from other tables like tblJobAdv,
and **give some more 'where condition' to those tables.**

```
SELECT tbluser.fullname, tbluser.email, tblJobAdv.advtitle, tblPersonalInfo.country, 
   tblPersonalInfo.city, tblJobOffer.digitalsignature 
FROM
   tblUser 
LEFT JOIN
   tblPersonalInfo ON tblUser.userid = tblPersonalInfo.userid
LEFT JOIN
   tblApplication ON tblApplication.userid = tblUser.userid 
LEFT JOIN
   tblJobAdv 
   ON tblJobAdv.advid = tblApplication.advid
   AND tblJobAdv.isUsable = 'Usable' /* some more where condition example */
LEFT JOIN
   tblJobOffer ON tblUser.userid = tblJobOffer.userid
WHERE
   tblJobAdv.userId IN (SELECT userid FROM tblUser WHERE email = 'h@y.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

It shows duplicate records because you are joining along different dimensions.  If I had to guess, based on the table names, users are applying for multiple jobs.

A quick and easy fix is to do `select distinct`.

Actually, you should check your underlying tables to be sure there are no duplicates in them.  I am suspicious about the Application table.  I think there might be multiple applications for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **group the records** or **distinct** will do (remove duplicates),

```
Select distinct tbluser.fullname, tbluser.email, tblJobAdv.advtitle, tblPersonalInfo.country, 
tblPersonalInfo.city, tblJobOffer.digitalsignature 
from tblUser 
left join tblPersonalInfo
ON tblUser.userid = tblPersonalInfo.userid
left join tblApplication
On tblApplication.userid = tblUser.userid 
left join tblJobAdv 
On tblJobAdv.advid = tblApplication.advid
left join tblJobOffer
On tblUser.userid = tblJobOffer.userid
where tblJobAdv.userId IN (select userid from tblUser where email = 'h@y.com')
```

Comment: ok bro, done but why it was behaving so ? any particular reason ?

Comment: I tell you bro, for example first row has a id=1 and join table has 2 rows with this id. So when you join both tables, you will get two rows right?? Getting it or shall I explain bit more?

Comment: @HunainHafeez bro accept the answer. It ll be helpful for me :)

Comment: i am searching for accept kinda button , but couldn't :(\i am newbie to Stackoverflow , help

Answer (score 0):

Please try select distinct to avoid duplicate records